# What does it mean in mapstruct to have @Mapping(target = "field", source = "")?

Tags: java, spring, mapping, mapstruct

I just cloned a repo with some mapstruct mappers (`1.3.1.Final`)
The build is failing due to following reason:

`java: No property named "" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "sourceField1"?`

I updated mapstruct to version `1.4.2.Final`, but with the same result.

Reviewing the code, I see we have the following situation:

- `SourceClass` with fields `sourceField1`, `sourceField2`, `sourceField3`
- `TargetClass` with fields `targetField1`, `targetField2`, `notInSourceField`

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    public interface TheMapper {

        @Mapping(target = "targetField1", source = "sourceField1")
        @Mapping(target = "targetField2", source = "sourceField2")
        @Mapping(target = "notInSourceField", source = "")
        TargetClass mapToTarget(SourceClass source);
    }
```

To solve the error above, I changed the line with `source = ""` to:

`@Mapping(target = "notInSourceField", expression = "java(\"\")") //means that notInSourceField = ""`

But I made this assuming that `source = ""` means that the value will be empty. Is this assumption correct, or what actually does it mean?

Comment: An interesting thing is that the default value for source is `""`, but the behavior is different and I am wondering why? 
For example, your target and source have the same property name, so you can specify only the target. Since default value `""` it means mapStruct will look up source property using a name in target, but if you explicitly specify `""` in the target, it will fail. 
In order to specify the default value, you can also use `constant = ""` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Information

### Why is the default value in the annotation "" for source?

The reason for the default value for `source` is that the annotation processor knows the difference between user defined `""` and the default value `""`. With the default value it will use `target` instead of the `source` unless one of `constant`, `expression` or `ignore=true` is defined.

```
@Mapping(target = "date", dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

In the above example, the `source` property is also named `date`, but for the conversion between `source` and `target` additional information is needed. In this case a `dateFormat`. You do not need to specify `source` in this case.

### source

This is what you use when the name of the property in the source class is different from the one in the target class.

```
@Mapping( target="targetProperty", source="sourceProperty" )
```

### constant

This is used when you want a constant value applied. When a field should always get a specific value.

```
@Mapping( target="targetProperty", constant="always this value" )
```

### expression

This is what is used when no other functionality of mapstruct is usable to solve your problem. Here you can defined your own code to set the property value.

```
@Mapping( target="targetProperty", expression="java(combineMultipleFields(source.getField1(), source.getField2()))" )
```

### ignore

This is what is used when you want mapstruct to ignore the field.

```
@Mapping( target="targetProperty", ignore=true )
```

## Answer

With the above information we now know that you tell MapStruct that you want to set the property `notInSourceField` to the property  . MapStruct does not find a method called `get()`, so it tells you that the property   does not exist.
The solution in your case would be as [Yan mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71399845/what-does-it-mean-in-mapstruct-to-have-mappingtarget-field-source#comment126204139_71399845) to use `constant=""` instead of `source=""`.

[You can find more information about default values and constants here.](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#default-values-and-constants)

Comment: At the end I had to interpret the `source = ""` as "I don't want to map this field, so what I did is to remove that line. In other class I found some other non String fields (Long, Integer, LocalDate...) with same situation, so I couldn't say a default or constant value for LocalDate. Unit tests were passed, so I think nothing is broken.. For now.
Thanks a lot.